# Syntax error reading from a text file / Want to assign each line from a text file to a different list

Tags: python, file, text

I'm trying to make a maths game and I want to implement a high score tracker which saves the high score of the person along with their name in the text file and it does that for every player. If the player plays again then it can recall his high score from the text file. Here is my code so far:

```
import random
def game():
    while 1:
        c1 = input("Would you like to play from the beginning?").lower()
        if c1 == "yes":
            lvl1()
        elif c1 == "no":
            print("Your score was:", score)
            main()
            break
        else:
            game()
    quit()
def lvl1():
    print("LEVEL 1")
    global score
    score = 0
    operators = ("+","-")
    while 1:
        No1 = random.randint(1,10)
        No2 = random.randint(1,10)
        Op = random.choice(operators)
        if Op == "+":
            A1 = No1 + No2
            print("What is", No1, Op, No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        elif Op == "-":
            A1 = No1 - No2
            print("What is", No1,Op,No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        if answer == A1:
            print("Correct!")
            score = score + 1
            print(score)
        else:
            print("Incorrect! Try again...")
            game()
        if score == 5:
            break
    print("Congratulations on making it to level 2!")
    lvl2()
def lvl2():
    print("LEVEL 2")
    global score
    score = 5
    operators = ("+","-","x")
    while 1:
        No1 = random.randint(1,15)
        No2 = random.randint(1,15)
        Op = random.choice(operators)
        if Op == "+":
            A1 = No1 + No2
            print("What is", No1, Op, No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        elif Op == "-":
            A1 = No1 - No2
            print("What is", No1,Op,No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        else:
            A1 = No1 * No2
            print("What is", No1,Op,No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        if answer == A1:
            print("Correct!")
            score = score + 1
            print(score)
        else:
            print("Incorrect! Try again...")
            game()
        if score == 10:
            break
    print("Congratulations on making it to level 3!")
    lvl3()
def lvl3():
    print("LEVEL 3")
    global score
    score = 10
    operators = ("+","-","x")
    while 1:
        No1 = random.randint(10,50)
        No2 = random.randint(10,50)
        Op = random.choice(operators)
        if Op == "+":
            A1 = No1 + No2
            print("What is", No1, Op, No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        elif Op == "-":
            A1 = No1 - No2
            print("What is", No1,Op,No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        else:
            A1 = No1 * No2
            print("What is", No1,Op,No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        if answer == A1:
            print("Correct!")
            score = score + 1
            print(score)
        else:
            print("Incorrect! Try again...")
            game()
        if score == 15:
            break
    print("Congratulations on making it to level 4!")
    lvl4()
def lvl4():
    print("LEVEL 4")
    global score
    score = 15
    operators = ("+","-","x")
    while 1:
        No1 = random.randint(10,100)
        No2 = random.randint(10,100)
        Op = random.choice(operators)
        if Op == "+":
            A1 = No1 + No2
            print("What is", No1, Op, No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        elif Op == "-":
            A1 = No1 - No2
            print("What is", No1,Op,No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        else:
            A1 = No1 * No2
            print("What is", No1,Op,No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        if answer == A1:
            print("Correct!")
            score = score + 1
            print(score)
        else:
            print("Incorrect! Try again...")
            game()
        if score == 20:
            break
    print("Congratulations! You have completed the game.")
    main()
def gethighscore():
    # Default high score
    highscore = 0

    # Try to read the high score from a file
    try:
        highscorefile = open("highscore.txt", "r")
        name = str(highscorefile.read())
        highscore = int(highscorefile.read())
        highscorefile.close()
        print("The high score is", highscore)
    except IOError:
        # Error reading file, no high score
        print("There is no high score yet.")


    return highscore


def savehighscore(new_high_score):
    try:
        # Write the file to disk
        highscorefile = open("highscore.txt", "w")
        L = [name, new_high_score]
        highscorefile.write(str(L))
        highscorefile.close()
    except IOError:
        # Hm, can't write it.
        print("Unable to save the high score.")


def main():
    # Get the high score
    highscore = gethighscore()
    if score < highscore:
        print("Yea! New high score!")
        savehighscore(score)
    else:
        print("Better luck next time.")


print("Welcome to the maths game.")
name = input("What is your name?")
print("IT'S TIME!")
lvl1()
quit()
```

I am currently getting this error:

```
Your score was: 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\A level computer science\Maths game.py", line 182, in <module>
    lvl1()
  File "D:\A level computer science\Maths game.py", line 37, in lvl1
    game()
  File "D:\A level computer science\Maths game.py", line 9, in game
    main()
  File "D:\A level computer science\Maths game.py", line 171, in main
    highscore = gethighscore()
  File "D:\A level computer science\Maths game.py", line 146, in gethighscore
    highscore = int(highscorefile.read())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: That's not a syntax error.

Comment: Please read [“How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example”](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What do you think `name = str(highscorefile.read())` &  `highscore = int(highscorefile.read())` do?

Comment: I thought that - that would extract the file content and assign the integer to the variable highscore and assign the string part to name

Answer (score 1):

A list cannot be directly written to a file, but in the following line:

```
highscorefile.write(str(L))
```

It is converted to a *string*. When you are reading the file in `gethighscore()` the result is also a *string*, **not a list**.

There are many ways you can save and read highscore. Let me show you a very simple method:

First import module named `ast`. Then change your `gethighscore()`

```
def gethighscore():
    # Default high score
    highscore = 0

    # Try to read the high score from a file
    try:
        highscorefile = open("highscore.txt", "r")
        fileContent = highscorefile.read()
        highscorefile.close()

        # This converts a string list to list

        L = ast.literal_eval(fileContent)
        name = L[0]
        highscore = L[1]
        print("The high score is", highscore)
    except IOError:
        # Error reading file, no high score
        print("There is no high score yet.")


    return highscore
```

Hope it helps! Comment if you still have any issues.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response i tried using your code and i think im still getting the same result.

Comment: Can you tell me which error are you getting right now?